# Adding new Spring Social connections to the same user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I am using Spring Social along with Spring Boot and Spring Security. I use Spring Social to provide authentication into our web service. This is done using the [SocialAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-socialauthenticationfilter-code) approach.

I am trying to support the ability to have a single user (ie. `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`) have multiple Spring Social connections. This way a user could sign in with either his Google credentials or Facebook credentials.

If I go directly into my database I can make this configuration. Then I can sign into the same Spring Security account for different Spring Social connections. The problem is the point at which a user adds the new connection. I'll give a sample of what I'm doing with the assumption that I'm signed in via a Google account and want to add Facebook.

I log in via Google. Then if I load either my Spring Security `formLogin().loginPage()` or go straight to `auth/facebook` (the standard Spring Social Facebook login URL), I can perform Facebook authentication. But, the result is that my current `Authentication` object (from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`) is an anonymous authentication user. This does make sense because I just logged in using Facebook. But at the same time I'd like to know that I'm logged in so that I could ask the user about connecting the accounts and setup the database.

How can I provide the ability to let an authenticated user add a new social account to his user account? Also, I'm not tied to a particular workflow for adding new connections; the above was just my first set of experiments.

- Spring Social 1.1.4
- Spring Boot 1.3.8
- Spring Security & MVC - as
  specified by Spring Boot 1.3.8

**Update**

From Jerome's suggestion I extracted the security filter chain from Spring Security debugging:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  SocialAuthenticationFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not an issue with Spring Social, but rather with Spring Security. If you get an anonymous user logged in, then it means that `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` is kicking in before yours, or `SocialAuthenticationFilter`.

Switch spring security to debug:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.debug(true);
  }
}
```

And check which filters are involved. I'm pretty sure you have the anonymous filter which kicks in for undesired paths.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I enabled debugging for Spring Security and found the filter chain. I put it in my question. However, the `SocialAuthenticationFilter` does come before the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`.